# Failing to write german 'umlauts' (äöü) from console to text file with java

Tags: java, utf-8, console, diacritics

currently I'm desperately trying to write german umlauts, read from the console, into a utf8 encoded text file on windows 7.

Here is the code to setup the scanner:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF8");
```

Here is the code to read the string:

```
String s = scanner.nextLine();
```

Here is the code to write into a file:

```
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(this.targetFile), "UTF8");

osw.write(s);
```

Unfortunately, instead of example "überraschung" the so written file is encoded in utf8 but will not display the umlaut. What to do?

Comment: what do you mean by "the file will not display the umlaut" ? How do you display the resulting file, and what do you see exactly ?

Comment: I open the resulting file in any text editor (Notepad++ or Notepad, both display the same). Instead of the umlaut I see a placeholder sign like an empty rectangular or a square with a questionmark.

Comment: are you sure that the console input is encoded in utf-8? Does the font you use to display the output support umlauts? Does the editor you use support utf-8?

Comment: 100% sure. Notepad++ shows the file as utf8 encoded and I can add umlauts manually with the editor. Except Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF8"); I don't know how else I could set the input to utf8.

Comment: Try adding this line, `System.out.println(s.contains("ü"));`, if it's `true` it's Notepad++ fault, if it says `false` System.in isn't utf-8.

Comment: @yan.kun the console encoding can not be controlled from java, you only change how java interprets the already encoded bytes, which will mess up anything not within the ascii charset if the console encoding is not utf-8. The default encoding used by scanner should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your console probably is not UTF-8, so when you do `new Scanner(System.in, "UTF8");` you are creating a scanner with the wrong encoding, and your umlauts are lost when you try to read lines from the console.

You may want to use `chcp` on a console prompt to check what code page is being used.

In fact, you might not need to specify an encoding at all. If you just create the scanner as `new Scanner(System.in)`, the default platform encoding should be used.

Comment: Thanks, actually it was fault of the console. I've tested the windows cmd and Netbeans one, which both failed. In the console of eclipse it worked without any flaws.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem (The String "ç" would not be "detected" by the Scanner and Strings like "Açores" would have the ç character "garbled").

I solved it by declaring the charset for the language:

```
Scanner keyboardReader = new Scanner(System.in, "iso-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, with german umlauts:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;


public class P {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = stdin.readLine();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:/p.txt"), "UTF-8");
        osw.write(s);
        osw.close();
    }
}
```